# Trying to understand, the meaning of this Powershell command

Tags: python, powershell

I have been searching online for a guide to python coding. In this website, https://learnpythonthehardway.org

The author mentions this code if python is not detected in Windows powershell. 
-> `[ENVIRONMENT]::SETENVIRONMENTVARIABLE("PATH", "$ENV:PATH;C:\PYTHON27", "USER")`

So what does this code do exactly? I will like to understand this and not just copy and paste into the powershell.

Comment: what's there to understand? `set environment variable` can't you see that?

Comment: you don't have to be a coder understand english, you know?

Answer (score 1):

```
[ENVIRONMENT]::SETENVIRONMENTVARIABLE("PATH", "$ENV:PATH;C:\PYTHON27", "USER")
```

It sets the environment variable `PATH` to the value composed of the previous value of PATH augmented with `C:\PYTHON27`

The environment variable is set for the current user i.e. at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`

in contrast with "MACHINE", which would set it system-wide i.e in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

or "PROCESS" which would set it for the current process.

Answer (score 1):

It does exactly what the function name (`Setenvironmentvariable()`) says it does. It sets the value of the environment variable `PATH` to the current value of the `PATH` environment variable, followed by the path to your Python directory. The last argument is optional but dictates whether the scope of the variable.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx (the first result of a search for `[ENVIRONMENT]::SETENVIRONMENTVARIABLE`)